Using github actions env vars to run different base Urls in feature and staging for snowflake Cypress test
I have a suite of Cypress tests that all use the same base Url except for one legacy test. The legacy test is using a before hook which has a cy.visit of http://e2etest.dev.my-company.com:8081/company/sign-in. The problem is that this test is running e2etest.dev even when ran against staging.
I created an if statement in the relevant code:
if (Cypress.env('CYPRESS_ENV') === 'test') {
        cy.visit('http://e2etest.dev.my-company.com:8081/company/sign-in');
      } else {
        cy.visit('http://e2etest.staging.my-company.com:8081/company/sign-in');
}


I also have a Github Actions ci.yaml. I do not have an e2e.yaml. The way the ci.yaml works is it takes in the branch name and it runs this:
echo "GITHUB_REF_NAME=${GITHUB_REF_NAME}"
          BUILD_REF="${GITHUB_REF_NAME}"
          FORMATTED_BUILD_REF="$(echo $BUILD_REF | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/-/g')"
          VERSION="$(date -u +'%Y%m%d')-$GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER-${GITHUB_SHA:0-7}"
          SERVICE='my-company-pro'
          case "${GITHUB_REF_NAME}" in
            "master")
              BASE_URL="https://e2etest.my-company.com"
              API_HOST="api.my-company.com"
              NAMESPACE="app-prod"
              ;;
            "staging")
              BASE_URL="https://e2etest.staging.my-company.com"
              API_HOST="api.staging.my-company.com"
              NAMESPACE="app-staging"
              CF_WORKER_ENV="staging"
              ;;
            "sandbox")
              BASE_URL="http://e2etest.sandbox.my-company.com"
              API_HOST="api.sandbox.my-company.com"
              NAMESPACE="app-sandbox"
              ;;
            *)
              BASE_URL="https://e2etest.dev.my-company.com:3003"
              API_HOST="api.staging.my-company.com"
              NAMESPACE="app-test"
              CF_WORKER_ENV="test"
              ;;

In the cypress job, I printed out what variables are available and I got this back, indicating I edited the yaml correctly:
Run echo "CF Worker Env: staging" 
CF Worker Env: staging

and
Run echo "CYPRESS_ENV=${CYPRESS_ENV}"
CYPRESS_ENV=staging

These values say test on a feature branch and staging on the staging branch. In Cypress dashboard I can see that on a feature branch, it's going to the if statement for the dev environment and I can see my console.log(Cypress.env('CYPRESS_ENV')) printed out the word test
However, when the test merges into staging in my pipeline it still prints the word test and goes to the dev environment.
Here is my cypress.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  pageLoadTimeout: 60000,
  blockHosts: '*datadoghq.com',
  projectId: '5cwnfh',
  defaultCommandTimeout: 40000,
  requestTimeout: 40000,
  responseTimeout: 40000,
  execTimeout: 15000,
  taskTimeout: 15000,
  viewportWidth: 1440,
  viewportHeight: 900,
  numTestsKeptInMemory: 0,
  retries: {
    runMode: 2,
  },
  env: {
    COMPANY_API_BASE_URL: 'api.staging.my-company.com',
    CYPRESS_ENV: 'test',
  },
  e2e: {
    fixturesFolder: 'fixtures',
    baseUrl: 'https://e2etest.dev.my-company.com:3003',
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
  },

  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: 'next',
      bundler: 'webpack',
    },
  },
});


I think the test is failing in CI because of my CYPRESS_ENV I put in my cypress.config.ts while I was troubleshooting. However, if I take out the CYPRESS_ENV from my config.ts, the test goes to the else block and runs against staging when I run it locally because in the console.log when I'm running locally, it's printing out "undefined"
How do I make Cypress run the 'test' env for CYPRESS_ENV locally, the 'test' env for CYPRESS_ENV when GITHUB_REF is not staging in CI, and the 'staging' env for CYPRESS_ENV when GITHUB_REF is staging in CI?
In other projects, I have a command in the cypress job in CI where I can adjust the values in command line but this test runs cypress automatically. Here is my cypress job in CI:
  cypress-test:
    needs: [workflow-info, build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      WORKER_ENV: ${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.cf-worker-env }}
      BASE_URL: ${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.base-url }}
      API_BASE_URL: ${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.api-host }}
      CYPRESS_ENV: ${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.cf-worker-env }} 
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        containers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          cache: 'yarn'
          node-version: '20.9.0'
      - name: Install Specific Chrome Version
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install -y wget
          sudo wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
          sudo apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
      - name: Get yarn cache directory path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "dir=$(yarn cache dir)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: yarn-${{ hashFiles('yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            yarn-
      - name: Restore next build and deps
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: |
            ./next/.next
            ./next/node_modules
            ./legacy/node_modules
            ./node_modules
            ~/.cache/Cypress
          key: next-build-${{ github.sha }}
      - name: Setup /etc/hosts
        run: sudo echo "127.0.0.1 e2etest.dev.my-company.com" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
      - name: Print CF Worker Env
        run: |
          echo "CF Worker Env: ${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.cf-worker-env }}" 
      - name: Print CYPRESS_ENV
        run: echo "CYPRESS_ENV=${CYPRESS_ENV}" 
    
      - name: Run App
        run: yarn dev &
      - name: Run Cypress Tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          browser: chrome
          working-directory: next
          record: true
          parallel: true
          config: baseUrl=${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.base-url }}
          ci-build-id: ${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.cypress-run-id }}-${{ github.run_attempt }}
        env:
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_DASHBOARD_KEY_NEXT }}
          DEBUG: '@cypress/github-action'
          CYPRESS_ENV: ${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.cf-worker-env }}  


Cypress will parse any CYPRESS_* environment variables as Cypress environment variables, dropping the CYPRESS_ part of the environment variable. Have you tried setting the environment variable as CYPRESS_CYPRESS_ENV? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-3-CYPRESS_

Looks like the test fails locally with the console.log coming back undefined if I do that. I'm going to assume the same in CI while I wait for it to go through.

The environment var CYPESS_ENV does not find it's way into the test code, most likely because env is a reserved word and is therefore rejected.
Experimenting
In a clean project (Windows syntax),
// package.json

{
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start1": "SET CYPRESS_ENV=legacy && npx cypress open",
    "start2": "SET CYPRESS_CYPRESS_ENV=legacy && npx cypress open",
  }
}

it('logs all Cypress.env()', () => {
  console.log('Cypress.env()', Cypress.env())
})

Running yarn start1 with CYPRESS_ENV=legacy, the above test logs empty environment object:

Cypress.env() ➤ {}

Running yarn start2 with CYPRESS_CYPRESS_ENV=legacy, the above test logs the environment value you want:

Cypress.env() ➤ { CYPRESS_ENV: 'legacy ' }

Note there is an extra space at the end of the value for some weird reason.
If you double-prefix the environment variable, then your before() code should work with a .trim() in the if() statement:
if (Cypress.env('CYPRESS_ENV').trim() === 'legacy') {
  cy.visit('http://e2etest.dev.my-company.com:8081/company/sign-in');
} else {
  cy.visit('http://e2etest.staging.my-company.com:8081/company/sign-in');
}


thank you, but if you look at my yaml above there is nowhere to run a script. It is taking the variable directly from the workflow-info job and running it for both dev and staging. I am not using a script, I'm using configuration files, so this might be helpful for someone using a different CI setup but it doesn't solve my issue.

Take another look at the answer, the script is just for illustration of the issue.

I tried setting CYPRESS_CYPRESs_ENV in my config file and wrapping this in the if statement       if (Cypress.env('CYPRESS_ENV').trim() === 'test') { and I got Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim') back from the test and the test failed to run
Additionally, this is helpful but I still would need to know how to use it with the github actions pasted above because i need an if statement for dev, an if else for staging and an else for prod. My issue is with env vars and github actions not just env vars.

It does work, I ran it on a local system, but sorry I can't tell what your issue is from the comment.

The GH action sets env just the same as local scripts, so obviously you want CYPRESS_CYPRESS_ENV: ${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.cf-worker-env }} assuming the ${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.cf-worker-env }} is correct syntax - most likely is if the other env vars are working.

I was not able to use the CYPRESS_ENV variables in my CI to do this but I was able to use this because the baseUrl is called in
 config: baseUrl=${{ needs.workflow-info.outputs.base-url }} in my CI. I printed out `console.log('base Url is', Cypress.config().baseUrl); to get this value.
 cy.window().then((window) => {
        const baseUrl = Cypress.config().baseUrl;
        console.log('base Url is', baseUrl);

        if (baseUrl === 'https://e2etest.dev.updater.com:3003') {
          cy.visit('http://e2etest.dev.updater.com:8081/company/sign-in');
        } else if (baseUrl === 'https://e2etest.staging.updater.com') {
          cy.visit('http://e2etest.staging.updater.com/company/sign-in');
        } else {
          cy.visit('http://e2etest.updater.com/company/sign-in');
        }
      });

Hopefully someone will find this helpful.
